# Use custom normalizer and normalization support

Tags: api-platform.com

I want to (de)normalise my data following the "example" found in the doc [here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/content-negotiation/#writing-a-custom-normalizer), but the `supportNormalization` method of `AbstractItemNormalizer` always returns false.

As the doc is completely unhelpful about what should be done, and how, could anyone help me here? I cannot find a working example anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First we can see from the definition of the method:

```
/**
 * Checks whether the given class is supported for normalization by this normalizer.
 *
 * @param mixed  $data   Data to normalize
 * @param string $format The format being (de-)serialized from or into
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null);
```

that this method returns `false` when your `$data` normalization is not supported by this normalizer. And only when this method returns `true` your `normalize` method will be called.

First parameter that `supportNormalization` receives is format e.g. `json`, `jsonapi`, `jsonhal`, etc.

So if you in your `api_platform.yaml` config have something like:

```
api_platform:
    formats:
         jsonld:   ['application/ld+json']
```

but you in your `services.yaml` register service:

```
services:
    'App\Serializer\CustomItemNormalizer':
        arguments: [ '@api_platform.serializer.normalizer.item' ]
```

`supportNormalization` will always return `false`, because your inject/decorate normalizer does not support `jsonld`, and you need to have:

```
services:
    'App\Serializer\CustomItemNormalizer':
        arguments: [ 'api_platform.jsonld.normalizer.item' ]
```

Here you have a list of [list of available serializers for specific format](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#available-serializers) (serializer for JSONAPI missing in doc).

In most cases I use (de)normalizer just to change/add some data, but that is possible if you decorate the normalizer:

```
services:
    'App\Serializer\CustomItemNormalizer':
        decorates: 'api_platform.jsonld.normalizer.item'
        arguments: [ '@App\Serializer\CustomItemNormalizer.inner' ]
```

Link to [decorating a serializer and adding extra data](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#decorating-a-serializer-and-adding-extra-data).

So at the end you need to inject the correct normalizer and decorate it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is better than all the docs. I wrongly assumed api_platform.serializer was a generic serializer for all cases, as I use jsonld but others as well. Also from the docs it seemed fine to register a normaliser only and not serialiser.. Anyways, thanks and sorry for answering late.